# LOAD DATA and LOAD_FILE in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql-workbench

In MySQL 5.5 I am trying to load a BLOB into a specific row. More accurately I am trying to Update a BLOB in a specific row using Ruby 1.8.7 (oldschool!).

My data came from a "SELECT INTO OUTFILE" and is therefore saved as a string. The data contains NULL characters, and that is where things get wonky.

I would like to know how to LOAD DATA from a file into a specific field.

*LOAD DATA*

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'my_file.sql'
IGNORE INTO TABLE table1
(BLOB_COLUMN)
WHERE ID_COLUMN = '12345678'
```

says that there is an unexpected WHERE. How do I get this type of functionality?

Or LOAD_FILE():

*LOAD_FILE()* cannot load the null characters captured in my data. Instead replacing them with "\0"

What can I do to stuff data into a BLOB at a specific field?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/null-values.html): `For text file import or export operations performed with LOAD DATA INFILE or SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE, NULL is represented by the \N sequence.` .. are you sure your problem has anything to do with `NULL` characters?

Comment: And load data can insert data into specific fields. So, pls revise your question and include more detsils about your problem!

Comment: @Shadow, can you elaborate on how to specify what field to load the data?

Comment: Check out the MySQL documentation on load data infile command, this feature is well documented.